# Spring Cloud Consul's gateway server returns Unable to find instance for mall-service-test

Tags: spring-cloud, consul

Please help.

I am using spring cloud consul 1.5.3 and spring boot 2.1.6. The default host and port that spring cloud consul uses to connect to the consul agent is localhost:8500. It works so far.

[image]

However when I change the consul host from 'localhost' to remote ip '192.168.1.89' and restart the gateway service, remote consul shows that Service Check is failed.
[image]
The output description is here:

```
Get http://PCOS-2019NFFBBI:8503/actuator/health: 
dial tcp: lookup PCOS-2019NFFBBI on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host
```

[image]
And when I visited URL http://localhost:8010/mall-service-test/ to redirect to my service mall-service-test, shows the error:

```
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.NotFoundException: 
Unable to find instance for mall-service-test
```

I use zuul gateway instead of Spring Cloud Gateway, it returns the same error.

Here is the spring cloud gateway application.yml:

```java
server:
  port: 8010
spring:
  application:
    name: angelcloud-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: mall-service-test
          uri: lb://mall-service-test
          predicates:
            - Path= /mall-service-test/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix= 1
    consul:
      host: http://192.168.1.89
      port: 8500
      healthCheckInterval: 15s
```

Comment: lol.I add this properties into consul config and solve the problem,it may health check cause:
` consul:
      host: http://192.168.1.89
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        prefer-ip-address: true
        tags: version=1.0
        instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.cloud.client.ip-address}
        healthCheckInterval: 15s
        health-check-url: http://${spring.cloud.client.ip-address}:${server.port}/actuator/health`

Comment: spring-cloud-consul 1.x and boot 2.x are not compatible.

Comment: @无处不在的二叔 I'm also facing the same issue, Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The Consul connection values need to go in bootstrap.yml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to go in bootstrap.yml, but it dosen't work.